# What is OCV times SCC?

Tags: voltage, current, generator

Is the product of open circuit voltage and short circuit current meaningful? Does it have any significance (in a generator, for example)?

Comment: No. That's like saying "I know the top speed of my car to be 100miles/hour" and "I know it could do 1000miles in a tank at maximum efficiency", thus a tank of gas always lasts me 10hours. They are two extremes, that cannot be compared.

Comment: Thank you for the responses! I think I understand what you guys are saying. Is there anyway to calculate an ideal power output with either (if the resistance of the generator is known)?

Comment: Sorry, this may be a better question: if generator A has a higher open circuit voltage than generator B, will generator A always have a higher power output than generator B (assuming speed, load, etc. are constant)?

Comment: To the first: Given either SCC or OCV and a true total internal resistance a decent estimate of operational power may be gotten, since that internal resistance is the limit that causes these two numbers and is "the missing factor" between them. To the second: Not guaranteed. If their loading on the input are same it's likely they are close enough, but their efficiencies may still differ. i.e. Both load the system with 50W, but one loses 5W in conversion and the other 20W, for example. But voltages alone are certainly pointless numbers to compare. 50V@1A = 50W. 10V@20A = 200W == more.